# Produce hits from one file to another using sed

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to produce "hits" found in one file to another using sed but i miss some parts of the substitution text and i cant find out why it wont work.

By using this command:

```
sed 's/\x1B[[0-9;]*[JKmsu]//g;s/.*(0x\([A-Za-z0-9]\+\)\.0x\([a-z0-9]\+\).*/(<Aug>Oct\2\1? Feb:Sep) -/g;s/.*(0x\([a-z0-9]\+\).*/(<Aug>Oct\1? Feb:Sep) -/g;s/.*}/(<Aug>Oct? Feb:Sep) -/' q1data.txt > 1.txt && cat 1.txt
```

i'm trying to keep some of the text and strip away text that i don't need. However on some lines it misses the text that i'm trying to grep.

Using this 2 files with the command above i should be able to get a correct result as i grep the red parts in the text but it fails at some lines for a reason unknown to me. The result from file 1 should be the same as q1hits.txt. (note that the files need to be opened in the terminal in order for the color scheme to work and the format)
[q1data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aj7egs19p5tcuuq/q1data.txt?dl=0),
[q1hits](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5z6xjdu5cn4rhnd/q1hits.txt?dl=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's/\x1B[[0-9;]*[JKmsu]//g;s/.*(0x\([A-Za-z0-9]\+\)\.0x\([a-z0-9]\+\).*/(<Aug>Oct\2\1? Feb:Sep) - /g;s/.*(0x\([a-z0-9]\+\).*/(<Aug>Oct\1? Feb:Sep) - /g;s/.*([A-Za-z\.]\+0x\([a-z0-9]\{3\}\).*/(<Aug>Oct\1? Feb:Sep) - /g;s/.*([A-Za-z\!]\+.0x\([a-z0-9]\{3\}\).*/(<Aug>Oct\1? Feb:Sep) - /g;s/.*([A-Za-z0-9]\+.0x\([a-z0-9]\{3\}\).*/(<Aug>Oct\1? Feb:Sep) - /g;s/.*}/(<Aug>Oct? Feb:Sep) - /' q1data.txt > 1.txt
```

The task was solved after a lot of testing and trying. Please comment if you have any suggestions for improvements.